# How does Azure Sql pool share resources?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-synapse

Could you explain some questions about the Azure SQL pool?   We have 4 DB in the Azure SQL pool with the following configuration:

1. SQL Pool  is 8 cores
2. Per database  from 0 to 6 cores

If four databases have the peak load at the same time how will SQL pool share resources between databases?  Will a pool work with 8 cores or only with  6 cores?
Will the SQL pool use 2 free CPUs if we have the above configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If all databases in the SQL pool are at peak load, it's better to estimate the vCores needed for the pool as follow:

For the vCore-based purchasing model:

- **MAX(<Total number of DBs × Average vCore utilization per DB>, <Number of concurrently peaking DBs × Peak vCore utilization per DB>)**

Yes, the pool will initially work with the 6 vCore and increase them as per the requirement to 8 vCore.

> If all vCores of an elastic pool are busy, then each database in the
> pool receives an equal amount of compute resources to process queries.

Please check the following important and useful link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-elastic-pools.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I understand when we configure a minimum of using v-cores, but how does the configuration of maximum v-core per database impact SQL Pool?    If we have 8 cores for the SQL pool and we have a max limit of using per database(6 cores), how will SQL pool use two free cores?

Comment: As the database maximum core limit is 6, it won't exceed beyond that even if the SQL pool has 8 core. You need to choose another database which can support more than 6 core.